# find the number of records that left outer join,right outer join and full outer join return

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to find the number of records that left outer join, right outer join and full outer join return. Given the number of records in left handed side table and right handed side table and matching records.

I am trying to correlate the relation ship between them. I have tried with two tables entering sample data. Could not get any relation ship between them. 
How ever if I know the number of unmatched entries in left handed side table. I will add that number to the matching records, then I will get the left outer join output. If I know the number of unmatched records in right handed side, then I will add that number to the matched records. It will give us right outer join output.

Is it possible without knowing unmatched records. Can we find the number of records that left outer join, right outer join and full outer join returns.

```
CREATE table table1(
    id integer,
    name varchar(40)        
);

CREATE table table2(
        id integer,
    name varchar(40)        
);

insert into table1(id,name)values(1,'ABC');
insert into table1(id,name)values(2,'DEF');
insert into table1(id,name)values(3,'GHI');
insert into table1(id,name)values(4,'JKL');
insert into table1(id,name)values(5,'JKL');
insert into table1(id,name)values(6,'JKL');

insert into table2(id,name)values(2,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(2,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(1,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(1,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(3,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(3,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(4,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(4,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(5,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(5,'ABC');

insert into table2(id,name)values(11,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(12,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(13,'ABC');
insert into table2(id,name)values(14,'ABC');
select count(*) from table1;//6
select count(*) from table2; //14

select count(*) from table1 inner join table2
on table1.id=table2.id;   //10

select count(*) from table1 left outer join table2
on table1.id=table2.id;//11


select count(*) from table1 right outer join table2
on table1.id=table2.id;//14

select count(*) from table1 full outer join table2
on table1.id=table2.id;//15


//Unmatched records`enter code here`
select count(*) from table1 left outer join table2
on table1.id=table2.id
where table2.id is null;//1

select count(*) from table1 right outer join table2
on table1.id=table2.id
where table1.id is null;//4
```

Comment: You need it in a single query or three different queries?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are showing how many records you get with the different join types and you also show how to count records that have no match. So what is it you are still looking for?

Comment: The only way to get those numbers is to run JOIN query. Run FULL JOIN to get all 3 at once.

Comment: Jim,Thorsten, Let's take an example table A has 100 records, table B has 200 records and matching records are 150 between A and B. How will you know the number of records that left outer join, right outer join and full outer join returns with out running the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the total number of records, knowing the number of unmatched records is equivalent to knowing the number of matched records. (Perhaps!)

The answer to your question is NO, you can't determine the number of records in different types of joins by only knowing the cardinalities of the base tables, without knowing how many records are matched (or unmatched). Simple mental exercise: both tables have 100 records. If all are perfectly matched, one-to-one, then all joins are the same as the inner join, and they all have 100 records. If there are no matches at all, the inner join has zero rows, the one-sided joins have 100 rows and the full outer join has 200 rows. And the only difference between these cases is the number of matched (or unmatched) records, there is absolutely nothing else that you might know that will allow you to get the answer without this piece of information.

ADDED after the OP asked a follow-up question:

In fact knowing "how many records are matched" is not well defined, and insufficient anyway. Suppose ALL records from both tables are matched. At one extreme, the matches may be in pairs: there is an id column in both tables, and the values in both tables are all the possible values from 1 to 100. Then the result has 100 rows. On the other hand, suppose the "id" is not unique in either table. Instead, it has the value 1 IN ALL 100 ROWS IN BOTH TABLES. Then every row in the first table matches every row in the second table, and the result set will have 100 x 100 = 10,000 rows.

This is just to suggest the following: "how many rows are matched" is not a well-defined concept. To have a count of the resulting joins (of different kinds), one needs to know what the joins are on, and for each tuple in the join condition, how many rows have that specific tuple in each table. Then the number of rows in the result set of an inner join is a sum of products of such tuple-grouped counts, and additional rows for unmatched rows from the left (or right, or both) table(s) for outer joins.

Comment: Suppose, even if we know the matching records how can we derive the co relation. Let's take an example  table A has 100 records, table B has 200 records and matching records are 150 between A and B. How will you know the number of records that left outer join, right outer join and full outer join returns with out running the query.